# BURG - Cant Boot computer because of BURG (PLEASE HELP!!)

Tags: boot, grub2, troubleshooting, burg

So I am very new to this, I installed Zorin 7 on my Laptop and it works amazing, however after installing BURG and GRUB I get this weird message and I CANNOT BOOT MY COMPUTER WITHOUT A SPECIAL DISK (made by a knowledgeable fellow at discount electronics, which I believe has the correct BURG installed,which is what allows it to boot, I believe.) I attached a picture of the message I get when I try to boot my computer without this disk and I have yet to see this anywhere else on the web. PLEASE PLEASE HELP me out with this ASAP people, I can't stand this. I would like to just completely remove BURG AND GRUB if possible or if not I would at least like to have this booting problem gone forever, so please help me out here.

Apparently I can't attach a picture without "10 reputation"?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove BURG

1. Startup your system
2. In a terminal type: `sudo apt-get remove --purge burg`
3. After the above reinstall grub `grub-install <target>` where the target is /dev/sda or whatever is your bootdisk.

Hope that helps

You may need to do `sudo update-grub` to do a search for the OSes.

[image]

Comment: is /dev/sda the default bootdisk for every computer?

Comment: Not necessarily, it refers to the first disk found. If you have multiple, it may be any disk.

Comment: How may I check what it is? and thank you so much for your help. I have another question,why do I need to reinstall grub? Id rather have it gone honestly.

Comment: Ah it is a necessary evil altogether. You see GRUB is a bootloader rather than a worm, which means it takes the linux kernel end effectively the whole system piggybacking on itself until it is ready to work on its own. To check the bootflag, open the disk utility and click on a drive and then check the screenshot.

Comment: Mine says bootable as well..

Comment: well then go ahead...

Comment: also it says my disk is /dev/sda1

Comment: your command will be `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: so now I continue with doing the commands you told me?

Comment: Yes please try.

Comment: so i will go back through the grub installation? and this time i will save to /dev/sda1?

Comment: /usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: Thats what it gave me when i entered sudo grub-install  /dev/sda1

Comment: Hello? I'm stuck here at the moment, has anybody else ever had their boot screen stuck on "BURG VERSION 1.98+20100....." "Bash like line editing is supported. For the first word. TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions......grub>_" and that's it. Im not allowed to post pictures yet, I just created this account and I'd really appreciate it if someone can help me thats dealt with this.

Comment: What happens when you issue `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` ?

Comment: Fixed it, I did try this before you mentioned it. Booted laptop without  disk, works fine. Boots through Grub instead of normal bootloader. Why would it say its called /dev/sda1 when that didn't work yet /dev/sda did? And thanks for the quick responses guys the help is much appreciated.